# How do we increase linux screen (the screen ultility in the terminal, not physical screen) scroll back limit?

Tags: gnu-screen

when I use the screen on a linux machine. I could use control A+ ECS to activate copy mode and scroll back.... However, it seems there is a scroll back limit. How do i increase this limit to as large as possible? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This question is very similar to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8760346/1466981) and so I've reproduced one of the very good answers below.

You can set the default number of scrollback lines to 10000 by adding:

```
defscrollback 10000
```

to your `~/.screenrc` file.

In an existing screen session, you can also press `Ctrl-a` then `:` and then type:

```
scrollback 10000
```

to get a 10000 line buffer, for example.